# Unable to delete row from html table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jquery to add new row as well as delete row. The adding part works, but the delete doesn't work at all, and I can't figure out why. It would work the first time, and the rest of the time it just doesn't work. Specifically, the only time it would work is when I click the delete on the first row.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="entryTable">  
            <thead> ...
            </thead> 
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>...</td>
                    <td>...</td>
                    <td>...</td>
                    <td><a href="#" id="addRow">Add</a><br>
                        <a href="#" id="deleteRow">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**Jquery**

```
var i = 1;
    $("#addRow").click(function(){

        $("table tr:last").clone().find("input, select, textarea").each(function(){
            $(this).val('').attr({
                'id': function(_,id){ return id+i},
                'name': function(_,name){ return name+i},
                'value':''
            });
        }).end().appendTo("table");
        i++;
    });

    $("#deleteRow").click(function(){
        alert("delete clicked")
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
```

I've tried changing `$(this).parent().parent().remove();` to `$(this).closest("tr").remove();` but that doesn't work as well.

I've also tried doing it like `<a href="#" onclick="deleteRow(this)">` and declaring a function deleteRow but that hasn't helped either.

Would definitely appreciate help or pointers here. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 $(document).on('click', '#deleteRow', function(){
        alert("delete clicked")
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
 });
```

Use **event delegation method** for dynamically created elements.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/92xVZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#deleteRow', function(e){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```